# generating subset in seaborn countplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm new here, so this is my first post. So I hope that I will do everything correct.
I have got a column where some country codes are standing, like US, JP and CH and so on. I want to plot the count of these, but only the ones with an occurrence of at least 4. I didnt find any way to do this, so please help me.

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
fig = sns.countplot(data=df,#.loc[(df["appln_auth"] >= 4,
    y="appln_auth",
    order=df["appln_auth"].value_counts().index,
    color="blue",
    )
plt.xlabel("Anzahl")
plt.title("Anzahl der Anmeldungen pro Land")
```

If you need a more in detail explanation of my aim, please let me know.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What is in `'appln_auth`'? You might be after something like `df['country_codes'].groupby('country_codes').transform('count')` or alternatively `counts = df['country_codes'].value_counts,  countries = (counts[counts] >= 4).index,  ...data=df[df['country_codes'] == countries],...`

Comment: in "appln_auth" are my country codes, like:

appln_auth
US
JP
JP
CH
JP

and I want to get a plot which shows me the count of these in bars, like:
3x JP
1x US
1x CH

Comment: Then just replace `country_codes` with `appln_auth` in my comment above. Either use groupby and transform to make a column of country code counts, or use value counts to get a list of the applicable countries and then filter on those. I noticed I said `data=df[df['country_codes'] == countries]` which is wrong, you will have to use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) instead of `==`

Comment: Ah I understand your way now, but your line:
countries = (counts[counts] >= 4).index
is giving me this error:
    countries = (counts[counts] >= 4).index
  ..........
IndexError: index 5366 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 20

Comment: I would look at what `counts` was before that problematic line (do `df.head()` for example) and see what the correct name of the field with the counts is. `counts[counts]` is def wrong, it might be something like `counts['counts']`, just check it in ipython. Oh wait, maybe it's just `countries = (counts >= 4).index`. Sorry that code was off the top of my head so I'm sure it has a lot of errors. But the idea should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that left parenthesis `df,#.loc[(df["appln_auth"] >= 4` in your code is unnecesary or extra. If removing parenthesis not worked for you, then do something like this:

```
df.loc[lambda df: df['appln_auth'] >= 4]

# or, may be like this...
df.iloc[:, lambda df: df['appln_auth'] >= 4]
```

`.loc[]` is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).